# Select child element of SoapException.Detail.InnerXML

Tags: c#, web-services, xpath, soap

I'm calling a UPS web service to calculate shipping and in the event of an invalid address, the service call returns a SoapException.

The SoapException has a Detail.InnerXMl property with the following XML:

```
<err:Errors xmlns:err=\"http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Error/v1.1\">
    <err:ErrorDetail>
        <err:Severity>Hard</err:Severity>
        <err:PrimaryErrorCode>
            <err:Code>111286</err:Code>
            <err:Description>CAa is not a valid state for the specified shipment.</err:Description>
        </err:PrimaryErrorCode>
    </err:ErrorDetail>
</err:Errors>
```

I wish to extract the text from the `<Description>` element.

Why would this not work:

```
try
{
}
catch (SoapException ex)
{
    XmlNode node = ex.Detail.SelectSingleNode("//Description");
    //node is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

parse the xml easily with LinqToXml:

```
var errors = XDocument.Parse(yourxmlstring)
                .Descendants("errors")
                .Select(e => new
                {
                    code = (int)e.Element("code"),
                    desc = (string)e.Element("description")
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: This returns a list of size 0, using `ex.Detail.InnerXML` in place of your `yourxmlstring`

Comment: `yourxmlstring` should contain your complete `SoapException` response message.